# Why has bing crawled only 1 page of my site after three weeks?

Tags: google, search-engines, bing

I don't understand why it's taking so long for Bing to index pages on my site. After three weeks after I added (and verified) my site, I find Bing has only crawled 1 page and indexed only 26 pages.

I found I had exactly the same problem with Yahoo. When I asked in here, someone recommended that I add my site to Bing, since the Yahoo SE was being replaced with Bing (or words to that effect). When I compare the indexing/crawling stats with the numbers I had with Google, the difference is mind-blowing (and probably explains Google's current dominance in the SE space). Within 3 weeks, Google had already indexed upward of 800 pages. I can't believe that the Yahoo and Bing SEs are that bad compared to the Google SE - so what on earth is going on?

Incidentally (as an aside to the main question), should the numbers not be the other way round - how come 1 page has been crawled but 26 pages indexed - doesn't seem to make sense.

Incidentally, should the numbers not be the other way round - how come 1 page has been crawled but

Comment: I'm wondering why do you waste time on those SEs? They won't bring you any benefit in terms of people viewing your site. If you rank well on Google you are going to rank well automatically also on those SEs.

Answer (score 2):

Get backlinks (get your link placed on other websites).

Bing and Yahoo are especially sensitive to backlinks and the anchor text of the backlink (what a link says).

I'll venture to say that your website doesn't have too many links pointing back to it which gives it low visibility to search engines, especially those not as sophisticated as Google.

Finally, it's a good idea to generate a [sitemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map) for your website that's available to search engines. Sitemaps make it easier for web crawlers to understand the navigation and hierarchy of your website. If you're using software like Wordpress, there are probably plug-ins/add-ons that generate sitemaps for you and automatically submit them to search engines.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem for a long period. Even til now. So I never rely on them at all. I use for [majesticseo](http://article-stack.com/knowledge/review-2/is-google-not-good-for-back-link-search.amty) or google webmaster tools the same purpose.

As per my experience, with proper pinging, yahoo index a page before then google and bing. then google and then Bing.